# Wordpress: Force https into http in my sitemap

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https, sitemap

How to force my sitemap url into http only?

Is it possible to do it in `.htaccess`? Because SSL is forcing all URLs into https including the sitemap page.

Here is the code:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
    https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd">
```

I want to make it:

```
    <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xsi="htts://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you are quoting though is not part of the URLs listed in the sitemap, so not sure I understand your question fully.

But if you want your sitemap file to reside on a different http vs https than the URLs in the website:

If your website pages reside on https, so will the URLs in the sitemap.

That is part of the standard Google set for XML sitemaps.

You can try check this article for more info:
http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/help/multiple-domains-xml-sitemaps/

Answer (score 0):

In case you need only few webpages of WordPress to enable HTTPS, you can use CNAME to redirect to virtually subdomain looking urls. Example :

Your WordPress is installed at :

http ://example-wordpress.com/
In this case your login URL will be at :

http ://example-wordpress.com/wp-login.php
But you love to have a funky HTTPS Login URL at :

https ://login.example-wordpress.com
In this case, you will need wild card SSL certificate (CNAME is not a Protocol) for the whole server and sub domains or only sub domains. Obviously redirect the http and https real login webpage with .htaccess too, otherwise the normal redirection to wp-admin will not work

if that method didnt work try To force HTTPS in the admin area, put this line in your wp-config.php file at the root of your WordPress install:

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);